# What are the NPC tells when drunk in Poker Night 2?

Tags: poker-night-2

In Poker Night 2, players (Brock, Claptrap, Ash, Sam) will give off different tells as you get them more drunk by ordering drinks. What are these tells?

Comment: More of a guess but from my observation some tells are: Brock - actually says damn it or slams the table, Ash: Face palms, Sam: puts his head on the table and rests his chin for a moment. these seem to be signs of a bad hand for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tells are the same, they just happen more. As for some clarification, here is the wiki for it http://theinventory.wikia.com/wiki/Tells

Answer (score -1):

Sam hops and his hat pops off his head a bit.

The tells listed above are not tells.  Those are regular actions that players do without drinking.

Comment: What about the other three?  You could greatly improve your answer by adding tells for all 4.

Comment: Also, what kind of tell is it when Sam hops? I imagine the characters will have tells for good hands, bad hands, and bluffing.

Comment: Those ARE tells. Characters have them even when they're not drunk, but drinking means they have more of them.